# Manipulate Input data before save in Laravel using Eloquent events

Tags: forms, laravel, request, eloquent

Is there any way I can do this?

```
MyModel::saving(function($content) {
    if(!Input::has('confirmed')) {
        Input::merge(['confirmed' => '0']);
    }
});
```

Currently the input isn't actually changing. I'm trying to systematically add in unchecked checkboxes (named 'confirmed') to the Input so that they save correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the events of the model using a boot function right inside the model you are working on

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // Setup event bindings...
    MyModel::saving(function($content)
    {
        if(!Input::has('confirmed')) {
            Input::merge(['confirmed' => '0']);
        }
                // $content->confirmed = '0';
    });
}
```

`$content` in the callback function would be the object you are attempting to save so you can get or set it's properties as you need.